# using curlpp on Windows. how to start

Tags: c++, mingw, libcurl

I'm newbie to c++, and I'm using mingw compiler. the last line

```
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
....
string url ("http://www.google.com");
curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;
curlpp::options::Url myUrl(url);
```

throws the following long error while compilation

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\ccpkmZ1C.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN6curlpp11Option
TraitISsL10CURLoption10002EED1Ev[curlpp::OptionTrait<std::basic_string<char, std
::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, (CURLoption)10002>::~OptionTrait()]
+0xb): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN6curlpp11OptionTraitISsL10CURLoption10
002EEE'
...
...
```

What's wrong here? Do I need to do something more then copying include folders from curlpp and libcurl to use curlpp?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linker error.

You need to add the `libcurl` libraries to the build command.
Something like:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -llibcurlpp
```

I am not sure of the exact name of the libcurl library.

Comment: mingw says that he cannot find -lcurlpp, the same for -llibcurlpp. I'm building with `g++ test.cpp -I include -o test -lcurlpp`

Comment: where are the curl lib files installed? Add "-L<curl-lib-dir>": `g++ test.cpp -I include -L /path/to/curl/lib/dir -o test -lcurlpp`

Comment: I'd puted curlpp folder in the same folder where test.cpp is. After adding `-L curlpp` got the same error

Comment: try specifying full path to the directory that holds the lib files.

Comment: the same thing. Do I have to do something more the copying source, and referencing to it?

Comment: You need the compiled library files. I don't know how libcurl is distributed but it sounds like you have just the sources for libcurl and not the library files. There should be documentation that states how to build the libcurl library. Once you have that then the compiler commands offered here should work for your test application.

Answer (score 0):

In your `curlpp` distribution (*.tar.gz* file, usually) you can find all the documentation you need. Basically, you may want to take a look at `README`, `doc\guide.pdf` and `include\curlpp\` directory for class/function definitions.

If you don't have any of these, make sure you get the [latest sources](http://code.google.com/p/curlpp/downloads/detail?name=curlpp-0.7.3.tar.gz&can=2&q=), as today.

Hope it helps.